# java.lang.RuntimeException: view must have a tag

Tags: kotlin, mobile, binding, tags

I have reviewed all the topics related to this issue in the forum, but since I am new, the solution methods I tried unfortunately did not work. Can you help me find where my mistake is if I share my code blocks?

```xml
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="country"
            type="com.example.kotlincountries.model.Country" />
        <variable
            name="listener"
            type="com.example.kotlincountries.adapter.CountryClickListener" />
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:onClick="@{listener::onCountryClicked}"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryUuidTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(country.uuid)}">

    </TextView>
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:downloadUrl="@{country.imageUrl}"
        android:padding="5dp">
        
    </ImageView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{country.countryName}"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/region"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{country.countryRegion}"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="5dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

my adapters code blocks

```kotlin
class CountryAdapter(val countryList: ArrayList<Country>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<CountryAdapter.CountryViewHolder>(),CountryClickListener{

    private lateinit var binding : ItemCountryBinding

        class CountryViewHolder(var binding: ItemCountryBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {


        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountryViewHolder {
            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemCountryBinding>(inflater, R.layout.item_country, parent, false)
            return CountryViewHolder(view)
        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return countryList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.binding.country=countryList[position]
        holder.binding.listener=this


    }
    fun updateCountryList(newCountryList:List<Country>){
        countryList.clear()
        countryList.addAll(newCountryList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCountryClicked(v: View) {
        val uuid =ItemCountryBinding.bind(v).countryUuidTxt.text.toString().toInt()
        val action =FeedFragmentDirections.actionFeedFragmentToCountryFragment(uuid)
        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action)
    }
 }
```

my click interface code blocks

```kotlin
interface CountryClickListener {
    fun onCountryClicked(v: View)

}
```

The error message I am getting is as follows:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kotlincountries, PID: 31993
    java.lang.RuntimeException: view must have a tag
        at com.example.kotlincountries.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:43)
        at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:79)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
        at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.bind(ViewDataBinding.java:736)
        at com.example.kotlincountries.databinding.ItemCountryBinding.bind(ItemCountryBinding.java:114)
        at com.example.kotlincountries.databinding.ItemCountryBinding.bind(ItemCountryBinding.java:102)
        at com.example.kotlincountries.adapter.CountryAdapter.onCountryClicked(CountryAdapter.kt:51)
        at com.example.kotlincountries.databinding.ItemCountryBindingImpl$OnClickListenerImpl.onClick(ItemCountryBindingImpl.java:173)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31993 SIG: 9
```

I have tried options such as invalidating/caching, rebuilding, etc.

Comment: It's a common error for beginner developers and has been answered many times before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803137/view-must-have-a-tag-error-in-android-data-binding

Answer (score 0):

`val uuid = ItemCountryBinding.bind(v).countryUuidText.text.toString().toInt()`

In the given code, you are trying to bind the View object passed to the onCountryClicked function with ItemCountryBinding. However, during this process, it's possible that the provided View object was not created through data binding, causing the error.

In the onCreateViewHolder function, you correctly inflate the view using DataBindingUtil.inflate to perform data binding for each item view. However, this binding process is executed only when onCreateViewHolder is called, and if you use ItemCountryBinding.bind(v) in onCountryClicked, the binding process will not be executed, resulting in an error.

If you want to use the onCountryClicked function, you can access the ItemCountryBinding object using the tag property of the v object.

First, add a tag to the v object in the onBindViewHolder function:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountryViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val binding = holder.view
    binding.country = countryList[position]
    binding.listener = this

    // Add a tag to the root view to store the binding object
    binding.root.tag = binding
}
```

Then, you can retrieve the ItemCountryBinding object using the tag property in the onCountryClicked function:

```
override fun onCountryClicked(v: View) {
    // Retrieve the ItemCountryBinding object from the tag of the root view
    val binding = v.tag as? ItemCountryBinding ?: return
    val uuid = binding.country?.uuid ?: return

    val action = FeedFragmentDirections.actionFeedFragmentToCountryFragment(uuid)
    Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action)
}
```

By adding the ItemCountryBinding object as a tag to the root view in onBindViewHolder, you can later retrieve it in the onCountryClicked function using the tag property of the v object. This approach allows you to use the onCountryClicked function while avoiding the "view must have a tag" error.