# Unresolved reference: databinding when importing databinding to MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

When I try to import databinding to MainActivity, I get an "Unresolved reference: databinding" error.

MainActivity file:

```
package <package-name>

import <package-name>.databinding.FragmentLoginBinding

class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentLoginBinding>(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_login,container,false)

        binding.register_btn.setOnClickListener { view : View ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_welcomeFragment)
        }

        binding.login_btn.setOnClickListener { view : View ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_welcomeFragment)
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

where package-name is my package name. The package name is recognized, only databinding is not, so it shows in red.

I guess because of that, FragmentLoginBinding in

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentLoginBinding>(inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_login,container,false)
```

is not recognized too.

Project build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
        gradle_version = '3.6.0'
        data_binding_compiler_version = gradle_version
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
    }
}
```

App build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:$data_binding_compiler_version"
}
```

I already tried to follow this codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-add-navigation/#0 and also search for solutions, but wasn't able to fix it.

Anyone can help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely it is because of an error in the data binding compiler. In other words there must be an error in some layout file for which the Databinding library is unable to generate the binding classes. You should check the gradle build logs for databinding compiler errors which are often at the end of the build log.

Comment: In my case the solution was: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66237310/3613808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was missing the layout tag in the layout to support Databinding:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 0):

[correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34713054/4075178)

Also wrap your root view with  tag

```
  var cropAdviceBinding: TemplateCropAdviceBinding? = null
        cropAdviceViewStub.viewStub?.apply {
            setOnInflateListener { _, inflated ->
                cropAdviceBinding =
                    DataBindingUtil.bind(inflated)
            }
            inflate()
        }
```